# Allign column of DIV blocks from aside of an other DIV block

Tags: css, xhtml

I want to allign div block in such maner:

```
+-----+------+
|first|second|
|     |      |
+     +------+
|     |third |
|     |      |
+-----+------+
```

But the following code allign it in other manner:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .common
            {
                border: 1px solid black;
                float: left;
            }

            #first
            {
                background: red;
                height: 100px;
                width: 50px;
            }

            #second
            {
                background: green;
                height: 50px;
                width: 50px;
            }

            #third
            {
                background: yellow;
                height: 50px;
                width: 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="common" id="first">first</div>
        <div class="common" id="second">second</div>
        <div class="common" id="third">third</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I won't use absolute positioning.
Is there some other way to do it?

Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap second and third in a container div and float the container and first.

```
#first {
    float: left;
}

#container {
    float: left;
}

...

<div id="first></div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="second"></div>
    <div id="third"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go: http://jsfiddle.net/4CD2s/

```
#first {
    background: green;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100px;
}
#second {
    background: grey;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 105px;
    width: 100px;
}
#third {
    background: grey;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 105px;
    width: 100px;
}

<div id="first">First</div>
<div id="second">Second</div>
<div id="third">Third</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a wrapper div width fixed with and overflow:hidden to prevent collapse

live example: http://jsbin.com/isuse4

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  
    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper {width:150px; overflow:hidden;}
.common {
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
#first {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
}
#second {
    background: green;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
#third {
    background: yellow;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="common" id="first">first</div>
  <div class="common" id="second">second</div>
  <div class="common" id="third">third</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know to do this is with 4 containers:

```
+-----+------+
|first|second|
|     |      |
|     |      |
|     |      |
|     |      |
+-----+------+
```

then create two more inside the second container:

```
+-----+--------+
|first|second  |
|     | +----+ |
|     | |3rd | |
|     | |    | |
|     | +----+ |
|     | |4th | |
|     | |    | |
|     | +----+ |
|     |        |
+-----+--------+
```

Float the 1st and second.  Don't give the second container any visual style, just position it.  Place the 3rd and 4th containers inside the 2nd as needed.  No extra margins on the "inner" containers and they will fill the space of the second, so the second container is really an invisible guide to help put them where they go, positioning only.

I prefer this method because it avoids any quirks of margins, and all you have to do to adjust the position both of the small containers (3rd and 4th) is to adjust the position of the 2nd,  They move along with it consistently.

Answer (score 0):

float first left

and give second and third the margin of the width of the first